# How to secure a code preview function?

Tags: web-application, secure-coding

Suppose there is an application which contained preview functionality, that means whatever the code (if it is PHP, HTML Python) the user writes, the user can preview the code.

For ex:

`<?php echo "hello this is test"?>`

When user previews it, user gets

`hello this is test`

Now what if a malicious user execute this:-

`<?php echo system('ls')?>`

He/she can get RCE and get shell

This is just a one case for PHP, there can be a lot. Also the application supports HTML, what if the malicious user injects the malicious HTML payload, that can leads to XSS.

I am looking for a way to secure the implementation of a preview functionality. So if any malicious user tried to inject malicious code and by the use of preview functionality, he/she can execute the code.

How can I secure the implementation of the preview functionality in such a way that when a malicious user tried to execute malicious code he won't be able to?

I am sure some will say disable such functions or validate the user input. Yes disabling these functions will help but validating the user input won't be feasible because that contains lot of code efforts.

So I wanted to know a good way to implement secure preview functionality.

Comment: Inject? Inject where? Why was this tagged with "penetration test" and "bug bounty"? Did you omit some context? In fact, I think you are missing quite a lot of context. What's previewed? Where? What risks do you want to mitigate?

Comment: @schroeder, I hope this make sense now?

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, executing code for the user is highly problematic. Reasonable solutions might use one or more of the following strategies.

- Don't do that. Unless you lock this down tight, your service WILL be abused for DDoS attacks, crypto mining, and so on.
- Actually evaluate the code in the user's browser not on your server, but this restricts you to JavaScript or stuff that can be compiled to WASM.
- Only let the user preview their own code. Under no circumstances host the code in a publicly accessible manner.

  - If users can only preview their own code, XSS isn't an issue – everything they could do like that, they could also do via their own browser developer tools.
  - If it does have to be publicly accessible, impose tight limits (limit available memory + CPU time, throttle max request rate, shut everything down after a couple of minutes) and serve the content from a randomized subdomain. The subdomain's root should be registered on the Public Suffix List so that browsers treat different subdomains as different sites, which is e.g. important for cross-origin requests and cookies.
- Execute the code in a disposable sandbox, for example a virtual machine or a container that is not reused. The code should also run under a non-root user. Note that Docker containers aren't necessarily secure by default, though it is possible to use containers as a security barrier when configured appropriately. Do not schedule untrusted containers on a Kubernetes cluster.

  - chroot() is one of the oldest sandboxing technologies around. It is a good basic security feature, but not sufficient by itself. Linux containers have much better security features (chroot() is effectively obsolete with mount namespaces).
  - The network should be configured such that the code cannot access other user's code. For example, you might have a firewall that blocks some or all outgoing connections. The firewall must not be part of the container with untrusted code.

Comment: Yes! Very informative, thanks. But I think if you can give an example for PHP type code, then it would be great or did I missed your point?

Comment: @CloudLearner It's not possible to add a bit of PHP code that will make everything secure. All of the points mentioned above require significant development and ops effort. E.g. using random subdomains would likely require running your own DNS nameserver. Starting with containers should be easiest though. A `docker run --rm --mount type=bind,src=/data/user1234/app,dst=/app,ro=true sandbox` with a suitable sandbox image is *close* to a reasonable configuration, but you'd want to drop more capabilities and use a more restrictive seccomp profile. Which requires low-level Linux knowledge.